# Capitalizing all copies of a word: why does this code fail when it's in its own function?

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I have two C-style strings:

```
char st[100] = "to be  or not to be ";
char sub_s[100] = "be";
```

I need to find the beginning of the "be"  with `strstr(st, sub_s)` and change it to capital letters. The new string needs to be `"to BE  or not to BE ";

I manage to do it with out the function like so:

```
void main()
{
    char st[100] = "to be  or not to be ";
    char sub_s[100] = "be";
    char* p;
    int i;

    while (p = strstr(st, sub_s))
    { 
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(sub_s); i++)
        {
            p[i] -= 32;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", st);
}
```

But when I put this code into its own function it doesn't work any more:

```
void main()
{
    char st[100] = "to be  or not to be ";
    char sub_s[100] = "be";
    replaceSubstring(st, sub_s);
}

void replaceSubstring(char* str, char* substr)
{
    int* p;
    int i;

    while (p = strstr(str, substr))
    { 
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(substr); i++)
        {
            p[i] -= 32;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", st);
}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Code and output should not be in images, you need to put the code and outputs as correctly formatted text in your question.

Comment: You are using `int *p` in your function example. Why?

Comment: Please do not post images unless they are absolutely necessary

Comment: @RandomDavis thank you. ill do it next time !

Comment: @16tons becuse as i understand i want to point to "be or not to be"

Answer (score 1):

In the function that you've written, you've set the type of `p` to be an `int*`, not a `char *`. This means when you write

```
p[i] -= 32;
```

the compiler will assume each element pointed at by `p` is an `int` and therefore take a step of size `sizeof(int)` in memory rather than a step of size 1 in memory. In other words, the code is interpreted as

```
Start at the location pointed at by p.
Jump forward i * sizeof(int) bytes.
Read an integer value from that location.
Subtract 32 from it.
Write it back
```

rather than

```
Start at the location pointed at by p.
Find the character i steps down from there.
Subtract 32 from that character.
```

To fix this, change the type of `p` to be `char*`, not `int*`.

This is the sort of error that would likely be easily detected if you cranked the compiler warning level up to maximum. I would strongly recommend doing that when you're learning to code, then asking questions about the warnings you get when you don't understand them.

Some other stray notes:

1. The return type of `main` should be `int`, not `void`.
2. Rather than subtracting 32 from each character, which works but isn't the clearest thing in the word, consider using the `tolower` function from the `<ctype.h>` header.
3. If the substring you're searching for consists solely of non-letter characters (say, `":-)"`), then this code can cause an infinite loop. Do you see why? Think about how you might fix it.

Comment: thank you! , i understand now/  but the tolower we didn't learn.why will it be infinite loop?   my while loop saying: try to find the substring in str, if yes do something. if not he will continue till the character '/0', no?

Comment: If you use `tolower` rather than subtracting 32, what happens if you try lower-casing all copies of `:-)` in the string `:-) :-)`? Play around with this and see what you find. If you're not sure what's up, post another question!

Comment: @chux Hahahaha, whoops, doing too much C++ recently. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef I still don't get why would there be an infinite loop if substring you're searching for consists solely of non-letter characters (say, ":-)")

Comment: @templatetypedef It won't since the function would return NULL and NULL is as good as false.

Comment: @SumeetSingh If the code uses `tolower` and the pattern string has no upper-case letters, you'll keep finding the same substring over and over again and replacing it with itself.